# Can SUMIF show blank for 0 result?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

`=SUMIF(Auto_Tracked!B1:B300,"rcumbaa",Auto_Tracked!D1:D300)`

I would like it to show blank rather than 0 if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply place your formula in an `IF` statement to give you a blank cell if the result is `0`.

Updated code:

```
=IF((SUMIF(Auto_Tracked!B1:B300, "rcumbaa",Auto_Tracked!D1:D300))=0,"",(SUMIF(Auto_Tracked!B1:B300, "rcumbaa",Auto_Tracked!D1:D300)))
```

This will check to see if the calculation results in a `0`, and leave the cell blank if it is true. Otherwise, it will use the calculation results.

Comment: I get an error in this formula

Comment: I updated the code. This one is tested.

Comment: =IF(SUMIF(Auto_Tracked!B9:B308,"tfavaro",Auto_Tracked!D9:D308)=0,"",(SUMIF(Auto_Tracked!B9:B308,"tfavaro",Auto_Tracked!D9:D308)))

Answer (score 0):

You could hide zeroes with a conditional format. Click `Conditional Formatting > New Rule` and select `Format only cells that contain...`. Make the rule `Cell value is 0` and set the text color to the same value as the background color (usually white).

Answer (score 0):

I would format the cells to not show a zero value.  Right click on the cells that you want to hide the zero in and apply the formatting for the positive value followed by a `;` negative values`;` zero values.  In the example below, the positive values show the cell color, negative values are red and the zero values are blank.[image]

Comment: format would not work in this case because I need 0's in other cells, I'm looking for something I can add to the formula like +if=0,"", - but not sure how to

Comment: You can format each individual cell.  Don't format those cells that you want a "0" in.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by a simple formula:

```
=TEXT(SUMIF(Auto_Tracked!B1:B300,"rcumbaa",Auto_Tracked!D1:D300),"#")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working if value is ZERO in any cells then It is showing blank of that value also instead of ZERO. It wants to show blank in that condition only where cells is blank or not matching with conditions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).